# User text input with an if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and have run into a challenge (for me). I've looked online for a solution, but to my surprise I couldn't find it. This must have a very basic solution!

The problem:
I want JavaScript to execute an if statement based on user input from a text field.

```
<input id="text_a" type="text;" />
<p id="answer"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var a=document.getElementById("text_a").vlaue;

if (a=="hello")
  {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Correct!";
  }
else
  {
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="Oops!";
  }
}
</script>
```

When I try this creation out, no matter what is entered into the text input (even the right answer) the else statement is executed. What am I missing to get the if statement to execute?? Thanks in advance for any and all help

Comment: You misspelled "value", try `a=document.getElementById("text_a").value;`

Comment: Thanks so much, though I'm very embarrassed now. lol

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Remove `';'` from type attribute

```
<input id="text_a" type="text" />
```

and you have spell mistake in `value`

```
var a=document.getElementById("text_a").value;
```

Here is working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WTVxu/).

Answer (score 0):

You've spelt value wrong:

```
var a=document.getElementById("text_a").vlaue;
```

Should be

```
var a=document.getElementById("text_a").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled value.

```
var a=document.getElementById("text_a").vlaue;
```